# Do I have to indicate all country visits on my Schengen Visa application?

Tags: schengen, switzerland

We are an Indian couple and are applying for a Swiss visa for a 10 day personal leisure visit to **Switzerland**. We understand that we shall be given the 'Schengen' visa which is valid for a few other countries other than Switzerland.

I also plan to spend 2 nights in **Paris** during my 10 day stay. I wish to know that after getting the Schengen visa, can I visit Paris as well without informing this in my visa application form. In my application form, I am stating that I shall be staying with my friend in Swiss for the entire 10 days (who of course shall be sending me invitation letter and other formalities).

I hope this does not cause me any problem when i check out of Swiss for France or during my re-entry to Swiss from France.

Answer (score 4):

A Schengen Visa allows you in general to travel to all Schengen member states.

Assuming that you fill out [one of these forms](http://www.bfm.admin.ch/bfm/en/home/themen/einreise/visumantragsformular.html) here for the visa, you should still add under point 22 "Member states of destination" Switzerland AND France. Since most likely you will be passing a passport checkpoint when traveling from Switzerland to Paris, I would not take the risk that they ignore the issue that you have not indicated beforehand your plans to travel to Paris. So you might be better indicating this beforehand to avoid questions, but they should not bar you from entering.

Comment: There is no passport control between Schengan states.  For all due purpose, flights between states are like a domestic flight in any other country (technically there are a few exceptions around customs, but they generally aren't relevant)

Comment: There are still periodical controls when going in and out of Switzerland - as opposed to other Shengen states where this does not happen at all anymore.

Comment: Supposing I specify 'Swiss & France' under column 22 'Member States of destination', then that will also mean that I will need to give my proof of return tickets from Swiss to France and as well as give my proof of hotel stay in France. ?

Comment: @user4557 I would suggest to do so